# Install a new OS after wiping out the OS on Samsung Galaxy Exhibit 4G

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, custom-roms

I have wiped the OS off of my Samsung Galaxy Exhibit 4G (T679). Now all I get is the flash screen.

How can I install a new OS at this point?

Answer (score 0):

All credit goes to stubbakatt over [HERE](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=20394682#post20394682) for the files and original instructions. I simply walked through it myself and re-wrote out the instructions in a way that caters to my brain.

**Disclaimer:** This has been tested on two machines - one running Windows 7 32 bit, and one running Windows 7 64 bit. This has not been tested on an XP machine (though it should work the same) or on a Mac. And of course, I'm not responsible if you brick your device, proceed with caution, etc. etc.

***FILES NEEDED:***

- **Drivers: [click here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1rC3Pne6YD1RXUtMlRSMGJPTkk)** (Google Docs automatically pulls up the content of the .zip - simply go to the top left and choose File then
  Download to download the .zip) - if you're rooted/rommed, you
  probably already have these, but just in case these are the drivers I
  used
- **"Back to Stock" - Odin, ops, factory image, etc: [click here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1rC3Pne6YD1OHVMSDZnN3dKeVU)** (Google Docs automatically pulls up the content of the .zip - simply
  go to the top left and choose File then Download to download the
  .zip) - this is the main stuff that Odin will use to flash your phone
  back to it's factory state

***STEPS:***

1. Make sure the computer recognizes your phone with the drivers above (again, this is probably already the case if you're having to do this!)
2. Unzip the "back to stock" .zip file to wherever you want - preferably somewhere easy to get to (desktop?).
3. Power down your phone. Once it's off, hold down the volume-down button and press power. Hold both down until you see the "Warning!!" message with the yellow triangle at the bottom. Once you see that, hit the volume-up button. This puts you into Odin/download mode.
4. Plug your phone into your computer.
5. Among the files you unzipped from the "back to stock" .zip file, open "Odin Multi Downloader v4.43.exe". Once it opens, the Message window at the bottom left should read "Added!!!" and "Detected!!!".
6. Make sure all four of the Options are checked (One Package, Auto Reboot, Protect OPS, Reset Time [mine's set to 300 seconds]). I don't know if this is all necessary, but at the very least One Package and Auto Reboot appear to be.
7. On the right side, click the "OPS" button, and select/open the Ancora.ops file.
8. At the bottom, click the "One Package" button, and select/open the "T679UVKJ1_T679TMBKJ1_T679UVKJ1_HOME.tar.md5" file.
9. The Message window should do an md5 check and end with "Check MD5... ok". If it doesn't, try redownloading again - don't want to flash a corrupt file!
10. If all of that is good to go, then select the "Start" button.
11. Your mileage will vary, but for me it took about 5 minutes, then the phone reboots itself into recovery mode (the little white box with the progress bar), then about 30 seconds after that and the phone fully reboots. Don't unplug it yet. After a few minutes (actually, the 300 seconds set in the "reset time" in Odin), it will say Pass!!! and you're good to go and unplug the phone.
12. However, we're not quite done yet. Our goal is to get back to a factory state. You'll notice a lot of your stuff is still in place - apps, etc. That's because this process doesn't touch the /data partition of the phone. In addition, it's possible you COULD still be seeing the Superuser app. If that's the case, simply go into your application settings (settings > applications > manage applications), find Superuser, uninstall it. It will say uninstall not successful, but it should disappear.
13. The last thing to do is simply a factory reset - this will wipe out the /data partition, back to stock, and you'll be done. This could also take care of Superuser, but I've never tested it to see since it's easy enough to do it before the factory reset.

So there you go - hopefully you're now sitting on an "out of the box" Exhibit II 4G to do with whatever you please.

[Original post](http://androidforums.com/threads/how-to-return-your-samsung-exhibit-ii-4g-back-to-its-factory-out-of-the-box-state.501539/)